# Hook into form handle from admin users table

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-meta

I'm adding a couple of buttons to the user table in a custom column, in which, on click will need to either approve or reject the user via `update_user_meta`.

I've tried hooking in with `profile_update`, but that didn't seem to work.

I also noticed that the form method is `get`, so would the best option here be some admin ajax?

[image]

TIA!

Comment: You can just link the button to the same page (`wp-admin/users.php`) and for example, you can use the `admin_action_<action>` hook to run the function which would update the meta - the button URL would have `?action=<action>&user=<ID>` which contains the action name and user ID.

Comment: It worked! Awesome. Thank you!